# Determining Information Priority using digital Survey

Tags: mobile-application, information-architecture, surveys

This question is regarding an **event/activity booking mobile application**.

The content users are served (offers and vendors) can be grouped by Regions (multiple) & Interest categories (6). Users must be able to Filter and Search the content on any page. Client wants Regions to be the main subject for splitting the content.

By the current clients draft, **Regions (multiple) and Interest categories (6) would not be a part of Filter, but have pages dedicated to each Category, Region, Region+Category.** Besides Lists of offers, List of vendors is also part of content (List of vendors and List of offer are different pages in the current clients draft). I find it hard to grasp what IA should look like (and would it be good).

Due to this, to make a better IA, I would like to understand **users information priority** when it comes to planing trips, browsing and booking events/activities using mobile applications. I'm currently limited to researching by conducting a (preferably single page) digital survey. [This is the research I took as guideline](https://medium.com/quick-design/a-ux-case-study-eventron-8c3c563099ec).

**I'm wondering if this type of questions would work for determining what content representation should be dedicated a page and what should be part of a filter:**

“You are performing a task of planning your trip 2 weeks ahead/ looking for events to attend in your free time tomorrow."

List of all Offers
List of all Vendors
Offer Categories (Music & Culture, Sport & Outdoor Activities, ...)

---

The solution I focused on would have everything on a single page (this wireframe is still missing search and values/dates selected in filter).

User could select Region from a dropdown.
User could browse multiple categories at once by selecting icon.
Offer color or/and icon would indicate offer category.
Has only 5 categories (I'm discussing with client weather one category should become a feature on it's own)

[image]

---

Are these open ended questions a good way to test for what filters shoud be present:

What information about an event is most important to you?
What criteria do you consider before attending an event?
What type of events/activities do you like to participate in?

Comment: Please see the [help center](https://ux.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Given the topic, you should be able to rephrase the question according to the rules of the site.

Comment: @jazZRo Which rule are you implying this question is violating? Could you provide more constructive feedback? A user posting their first question ever on UX.SE may benefit from more explicit and targeted suggestions.

Comment: @maxathousand I don't see what I can explain better in one comment than what is already written in the help center. The question here is to review the given survey questions and is also asking for opinions. The help center should give a good idea why that is not suitable to ask and how to avoid such questions.

Comment: I suggest that the same tips for structuring questions on a survey applies to this question. There aren't really any specific context about your users and the overall plan for the survey you are planning to publish that can be used to help make the question more focused at the moment. Perhaps tell us what you think would be difficult to capture in a survey that you would have preferred to do in an interview, keeping in mind that a survey has a potentially broader reach (quantity) but less rich in data that can be captured (quality).

Comment: I think I'm going to make a graph of current AI to make it easier to understand the problem. I suggested introducing tabs to the client. 1 tab for list of vendors, 1 tab for list of offers. Maybe tab per category would be a better solution. I guess I can start drawing more wire-frames... even without conducting a survey.

Comment: @MichaelLai I've changed my question and gave my idea of a solution. I guess the real question is how could I benefit from the survey, what would be right questions to ask at this point.

Comment: The updates to the question provides a lot more context to the scenario that you are proposing. I am wondering how you are currently determining what is and isn't a filter, because this would be the assumptions that you are trying to test, and so your survey should also try to validate some of these assumptions

Comment: Currently offer filters are independent of category - filter by "price per person" and "event/activity duration". I added (to my question) questions I'll ask to understand how filters should be. The existing platform used for ticketing has some limitations to how content can be filtered, I'll have to learn to understand it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm nearly done with analysing the results of the survey :)  As for the search/select Region element, I think we will go with the blank Search input field with Regions offered as the search suggestions when the user taps the search bar but hasn't put in any input yet. Thank you once again for the help.